# how do i delete a users message without query error?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am having trouble with my page redirect when deleting a users comment.  below is my code. It deletes the message but gives me this error: Message matching query does not exist for Message.objects.get(id=message_id).delete().

```
def remove_message(request, message_id):
    Message.objects.get(id=message_id).delete()
    return redirect(reverse('dashboard:show'))
```

^ABOVE FIXED:

new issue, cannot get my delete button to show when trying to delete only the current users comments. Code below:

views.py

```
def remove_message(request, user_id, message_id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id'])
    Message.objects.filter(id=message_id, user = request.user).delete()
    return redirect(reverse('dashboard:show', args=user_id))
```

show.html

```
{% for message in messages%}
<div class="message">
    <p class='bg-primary wall_content'><strong>{{message.messageuser.first_name}} wrote:</strong></p>
        <p class='wall_content'>{{message.message}}</p>
        {% if message.id == request.user %}
            <a href='{% url "dashboard:remove_message" user.id message.id %}'>Delete Message</a>
        {% endif %}
        {% for comment in comments %}
            {% if message.id == comment.message.id %}
                <p class='bg-success wall_content comment'><strong>{{comment.user.first_name}} wrote:</strong></p>
                <p class='wall_content comment'>{{comment.comment}}</p>
            {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of [`get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get), you can use [`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#filter) which returns `QuerySet`. Unlike the `get` method, the `filter` does not raise [`ObjectDoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/exceptions/#objectdoesnotexist) exception, but just returns a empty queryset if there's no matching object.

Deleting empty queryset has no harm.

So you the line can be replaced with:

```
Message.objects.filter(id=message_id).delete()
```

Comment: if I wanted to make it so that only the user can delete their own message, how do I do that? I tried putting and {% if message.id == request.session.user_id %}  in the html but then the button completely disappears.

Comment: @Jives, `request.user` instead of `request.session`. BTW, simply hiding in view is not enough. You need to also check in view to be sure.  `Message.objects.filter(id=message_id, user=request.user).delete()` for example.